# In which situations is TokuDB higher performance?

Tags: mysql, innodb, mariadb, xtradb, tokudb

I noticed that WordPress runs quite a bit faster when I use XtraDB (MariaDB's InnoDB replacement) instead of TokuDB. This is strange, because TokuDB is advertised as being 20x faster.

However, I noticed that YOURLS stat pages are a tiny bit faster when I use TokuDB for the gigantic (~22,000 rows) log table.

So the question is: What situations will TokuDB be a higher-performance database engine than others, such as XtraDB/InnoDB?

Comment: 22K rows is gigantic?

Comment: @ypercube Gigantic compared to most tables I have. I guess I don't have much data at all, according to your standards...
However, the table does have quite a bit of text per row.

Answer (score 2):

Unless your WordPress site is huge, you are unlikely to see much performance improvement in switching to TokuDB, if any at all. TokuDB's 20x performance advantage is for an indexed insertion workload, where the secondary indexes do not fit in memory.

You will be using less space on disk with TokuDB's compression.

Comment: To provide more background information, the largest wordpress installation in the world, Wordpress.com uses mainly Memory caching + MyISAM + SSDs + a good disaster recovery system.

Comment: @jynus, why does it use MyISAM?

Comment: That was true many years ago based on Automattic slides, I cannot say it is still like that nowadays (I hope not)